# rsync: Why doesn't --archive imply --recursive when --files-from=FILE is used?

Tags: command-line, rsync, backup, options, archive

Using `-r` or `--recursive` causes `rsync` to recurse into directories. `-a` or `--archive` equals `-rlptgoD`, so `-a` implies `-r`.

If I have directories `source/` and `dest/` and I run:

```
rsync source dest
```

then `rsync` skips `source/` and does not copy anything. If I run:

```
rsync -a source dest
```

then `-a` implies `-r` and `rsync` copies `source/` and all of its contents to `dest/`.

But if I have a file `list.txt` that contains the line `source`, and the full path of my directory `source/` is `/home/user/source/`, and I run:

```
rsync -a --files-from=list.txt /home/user/ dest
```

then `rsync` only copies `source/` to `dest/` but does not copy its contents. The same happens if I run the command without the `-a` option.

But if I run the same command with `-r`:

```
rsync -r --files-from=list.txt /home/user/ dest
```

then `rsync` copies `source/` and all of its contents to `dest/`.

My questions are:

- Why doesn't `-a` imply `-r` when the `--files-from=FILE` option is used? Is this expected behavior?
- Given that the command `rsync source dest` skips `source/` and copies nothing because `source/` is a directory and neither `-a` nor `-r` is used, why does the command `rsync --files-from=list.txt /home/user/ dest` still copy `source/` to `dest/`?
- Do the other options implied by `-a` still work when the `--files-from=FILE` option is used? Is `-r` the only option that is left out?

**Edit:** Looks like I should have read the `man` page more thoroughly. Under the description of the `--files-from=FILE` option it says:

> The  --archive  (-a)  option’s behavior does not imply --recursive (-r), so specify it explicitly, if you want it.

(Answers my first question.)

> The --dirs (-d) option is implied, which will create directories specified in the list on the  destination rather than noisily skipping them (use --no-dirs or --no-d if you want to turn that off).

(Answers my second question.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `-a`, `--archive`
>
> This is equivalent to `-rlptgoD`. It is a quick way of saying you
>             want recursion and want to preserve almost everything (with `-H`
>             being a notable omission).  **The only exception to the above
>             equivalence is when `--files-from` is specified, in which case `-r`
>             is not implied.**

When you use `--files-from`, the recursion is disabled (this is the only option left out).  It is assumed that the user knows exactly what specific files to transfer and that they have specified these in the file list that they use with `--files-from`.

If a directory is specified in the file list, its ownership, timestamp etc. will be synchronised, but not its content.

You may add the `-r` flag explicitly though:

```
rsync -av --files-from=file.list -r src/ dst/
```

This will have the effect that you are looking for.